# Finding two subspaces $\ T$ -invariant that

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\ V = \mathbb R^4 $ and $\ T: V \rightarrow V $ a linear transformation represented by following matrix (standard basis):

$$\ [T]_E = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1& 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $$

I need to find two subspaces $\ W, U \subseteq V $ that are $\ T-$invariant and $\ V = W \oplus U $ and that $\ T|_W $ is nilpotent matrix and $\ T|_U $ is invertible.

Finding $\ C_A(x) = x(x^2-2)(x-2) $ and using the primary decomposition I have:

$$\ W_1 = Ker(T) = span\{(1,1,0,0)\}, \\W_2 = Ker(T-2I) = span\{(1,-1,0,0)\} ,\\ W_3 = Ker(T^2 -2I) = span\{(0,0,1,0),(1,1,0,1) \} $$

So I have now $\ V = W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus W_3 $

I'm not sure how do I proceed from here, I also don't know what $\ T|_{W_1} $ look like for example ?

Comment: I'm 98% certain of this, which is why its a comment and not an answer. You need the $0$ eigenvector to be in one of the spaces,  that'll make $T$ nilpotent there.   Then have the nonzero eigenvectors form the other space.

Comment: @Alan can you please instruct me further how do I create a subspace from those subspaces that has the eigenvector $\ 0 $  ?

Comment: Find the eigenvector that goes with the eigenvector $0$, in other words, find the null space.    then find the eigenvectors for the eigenvalues $2, \pm \sqrt 2$,  those 4 eigenvectors form a basis for the space

Comment: @bm Take $W = W_1$ and $U = W_2 \oplus W_3$.